# print variable above of the while loop (scope) php

Tags: php, while-loop, scope

is there is any way to define a variable under the `while loop` and print it above the `while loop`

something like this

```
print $catName
while ($b = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
$catName = $b['cat'];
}
```

**EDIT**

```
$getBooks = $db->prepare('SELECT
    id, cat, instituteId, title, cover, authorName FROM books_library WHERE instituteId=? AND cat=?');
$getList = array();
$getBooks->bind_param('ii', $inId, $cid);
if ($getBooks->execute()) {
    $libResults = $getBooks->get_result();
    $getList[] = $libResults;
    ?>
```

HTML CODE COME HERE

```
<h3 class="marginBottom8px margin-top_30px text-bold text-danger"><?php echo catName ?></h3>
```

AND THEN THE WHILE LOOP

```
while ($book = mysqli_fetch_assoc($libResults)) {
                                $bokId = $book['id'];
                                $bookTitle = $bokId['title'];
                                $catName = $bokId['cat'];
                                $catName = $bokId['cat'];
```

now under the `while loop` I got the `$catName` How can I `echo` it above in the `<h3></h3>`

Comment: You can't echo a variable that hasn't been defined, that's like trying to feed a baby that hasn't yet been conceived..... explain what you're trying to achieve here, not how you're trying to do it..... ie __WHY__ do you need to echo a value from a database query before you've read the database query result.... __why__ can't you simply display it inside the loop?

Comment: why do you need to do this? maybe an alternative to what you want to achieve is in order.

Comment: give me sec I will edit my question

Comment: <h3><?php echo $catName ?></h3>

Comment: @Sajitha Nilan it will do if it's under the `while loop` not above I think!

Comment: then nothing will print. because $catName is empty

Comment: Why can't you move html code after the while loop. that the solution

Comment: @Sajitha Nilan thanks for effort I just was asking is there is a way?

Comment: Either have the markup inside the while loop, or after it, not before.... you can't echo a variable before it's defined, but you can move the echo to a point after it's defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the while block, put your `h3` html in a variable and print it.

```
$myHtml = '<h3 class="marginBottom8px margin-top_30px text-bold text-danger">' 
    . $catName . '</h3>';
print $myHtml;
```

Don't mix html and php like that.

Comment: If you mean put $myHtml before the loop... this won't work. $catName will be empty when the string is created.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you're after based on the edited question

```
while ($book = mysqli_fetch_assoc($libResults)) {
    echo '<h3>' . $book['cat'] . '</h3>';
}
```

Comment: this answer should not down vate. Because the question is @#@#@$@$